# Affect the UL using jQuery

Tags: jquery

I would like to make the UL to have red color in the border but I failed.

I don't know how to do it using jQuery.

```js
$(document).ready(function(){
    $("li.start").prev(".test").prev(".test2").prev(".test3").css({"color": "red", "border": "2px solid red"});
});
```

```css
.siblings * { 
    display: block;
    border: 2px solid lightgrey;
    color: lightgrey;
    padding: 5px;
    margin: 15px;
}
```

```html
<div style="width:500px;" class="siblings">
  <ul class="test3">ul (parent)  
    <li class="test2">li (sibling)</li>
    <li class="test">li (the previous sibling of li with class name "start")</li>
    <li class="start">li (sibling with class name "start")</li>
    <li>li (sibling)</li>
    <li>li (sibling)</li>
  </ul>   
</div>
```

Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

The `ul` is a ancestor element of the `li.start` element, [.prev()](https://api.jquery.com/prev/) is used to get only the previous sibling element - it wont find the ancestor element.

You can use [.closest()](https://api.jquery.com/closest/) or [.parent()](https://api.jquery.com/parent) to find the `ul` from the `li`

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  $("li.start").parent().css({
    "color": "red",
    "border": "2px solid red"
  });
  //or $("li.start").closest(".test3").css({"color": "red", "border": "2px solid red"});
});
```

```css
.siblings * {
  display: block;
  border: 2px solid lightgrey;
  color: lightgrey;
  padding: 5px;
  margin: 15px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div style="width:500px;" class="siblings">
  <ul class="test3">ul (parent)
    <li class="test2">li (sibling)</li>
    <li class="test">li (the previous sibling of li with class name "start")</li>
    <li class="start">li (sibling with class name "start")</li>
    <li>li (sibling)</li>
    <li>li (sibling)</li>
  </ul>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

How about just this:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $("li.start").parent("ul").css({"color": "red", "border": "2px solid red"});
});
```

Target the parent `ul` directly without using the siblings.

[Fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/hce7q5hL/)